# How to watch tasklist for running tasks

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, tasklist

I've been dealing with this for a while. I don't think I can find an easy solution. What I want to know is how many hours I play games.

Why does printing `result_1` return 0 sometimes and 1 other times? Why doesn't it return "No tasks are running..." or show me the running task?

```
import subprocess
from time import *
from datetime import *

command_1 = "TASKLIST /FI \"IMAGENAME eq Application-steam*\""  #Code for finding the "Banished" game
no_task_respond_0 = "INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria."

while True:
    the_time = datetime.now()
    result_1 = subprocess.call(command_1, shell=True)  # running this code prints the result whether i want it or not

    open_file = open("watcher.txt","w")
    current_task_file = open_file.write(str(result_1))

    print(current_task_file,"Inside of Current task FILE!!")

    if str(current_task_file) == str(no_task_respond_0): #If no games are running then continue
        continue
    else:                                                #If the game started then note the time

        date_file = open("datefile.txt","a")
        date_watcher = date_file.write(str(the_time)+"\n")

    sleep(4)
```

---

When I close the game, this is the result that it returns:

```
**INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.**

**1 Inside of Current Task FILE!!**
```

This is the output while the game is running:

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
Application-steam-x64.exe    14684 Console                    1    298.588 K

**1 Inside of Current task FILE!!**
```

These 1s are from printing `result_1`.

Comment: Don't use `shell=True` unless absolutely necessary. tasklist.exe doesn't need it. `subprocess.call` returns the exit code, but `tasklist.exe` always sets that to 1 unless there's an error in the command, so that's not useful. You could use `subprocess.check_output` to look for the name of the application in the output, which means it was found as running process. But instead I suggest you redesign to use [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil). It's API based instead of parsing command-line output, and allows a script to `wait()` until a process exits instead of polling.

Comment: Thank you sir im working on it.
I appreciate it.